# HTTPS on Elastic Load Balancer not holding HTTPS status

Tags: .htaccess, https, amazon-web-services, apache

I have a few servers behind a Load Balancer running Apache with PHP we're finding that people can't hold an SSL session. You can access any page on the site using https by adding https:// to the URL but when you click a link even though that link will show https you get redirected back to a standard http page.

On the Load Balancer listener page I have it set up as:

```
HTTP 80 to HTTP 80
TCP (SSL) 443 to TCP 80
```

I've tried non-TCP and using https and I've tried 443 to 443 but that throws a Server 503 error (server overload). I've added a `*:443` VirtualHost on the servers but that didn't work.

I also even tried a:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

as an .htaccess rule. But users are still being redirected back to HTTP when navigating.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the right track is having HTTPS 443 to HTTP 80, not TCP. Can you provide more details about what happens when you configure it this way?